# 1 pixel gap between media queries

Tags: css, sass

I use SASS(SCSS) and I have a little problem with media queries.

**What I have:**

```
$breakpoint-sm: 650px;
$breakpoint-md: 950px;


.something {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;

    @media (min-width: $breakpoint-sm) and (max-width: $breakpoint-md) {
           width: 80px;
           height: 80px;
     }
}
```

**What I want (mobile first):**

1. Between `650px` and `950px` **exactly**- **.something** should have
   `80px` width and height
2. Everything else - **something** should have `200px` width and height

**Problem:**
`@media (min-width: $breakpoint-sm) and (max-width: $breakpoint-md)` works from `650px` to `950px`. I want `650`, `949`. On `950` I want to apply `200px` width and height.

Is this solution correct?

```
.something {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;

    @media (min-width: $breakpoint-sm) and (max-width: $breakpoint-md - 1) {
           width: 80px;
           height: 80px;
     }
}
```

This solution works, but I think it's bad idea to subtract 1 from breakpoint (especially from variable).

Thanks

Comment: Just put in the actual values you want to use... `max-width: 949px`

Comment: No, it's not bad idea to subtract 1 from breakpoint. Otherwise your breakpoint from 0 to breakpoint and from breakpoint to inf will overlap

Comment: If it was a bad practice, then frameworks such as Bootstrap would probably not be doing it in exact that way … Of course you probably don’t want to do that subtraction directly in your media query all the time, so you should define those values as variables upfront as well. BS 3 for example has `screen-XY-min` and `screen-XY-max` classes specifically for this reason.

Comment: Does `$breakpoint-md - 1` work?

Comment: The poster's proposed solution is good, and produces the correct results.

Comment: Yes $breakpoint-md - 1 works fine. I'll create another variable with 949px value. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you’re reusing the `$breakpoint-md` as either the lower or upper constraint so can’t just make it 949px.

Using minus is fine, that functionality is in the browser for a reason

`@media (min-width: $breakpoint-sm) and (max-width: $breakpoint-md - 1)`

The other option is to specify the start and end points of each ‘size’ but I don’t think this is any clearer.

```
...
$breakpoint-sm: 650px;
$breakpoint-sm-max: 949px;
$breakpoint-md: 950px;
$breakpoint-md-max: 1199px;
$breakpoint-lr: 1200px;
...
```

Comment: Yes. I'm reusing the $breakpoint-md. I'll use the suggested variables from you. $breakpoint-sm-max and $breakpoint-md-max. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in SASS.

```css
$breakpoint:(sm: 650px, md: 950px)


.something {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;

    @include media('>=sm', '<md') {
       width: 80px;
       height: 80px;
    }

}
```

the @include media let you do the "bigger than", "less than" , etc

[@include media](https://include-media.com/)

Comment: Note that this requires an additional library.

Comment: yeah, the posts solution is still correct, if he wants something like "if(breakpoint > x)" can use this